# Обращение к select через jQuery возвращает 0, как обратиться к нужному элементу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такой init (ниже). Это список с 4-мя значениями, первое 0 остальные - сроки. По умолчанию стоит четвертая строка "American express", значение value в списке = "37". Как получить это значение из init? Указано, что в inint значение value: "37" При обращении к нему через companyfield = $('#resp_company').val(); получаем нулевое значение, это логично, т.к. val() возвращает значение первого элемента списка, а мне надо присвоенное значение. Признателен за совет.

```
<select name="resp_company" id="resp_company" class="w2ui-input">
   <option value="0"></option>
   <option value="3">Bank of Toronto</option>
   <option value="34">West Coast Bank</option>
   <option value="37">American express</option>
</select>



init [select#resp_company, context: document, selector: "#resp_company"]
0: select#resp_company.w2ui-input
0: option
1: option
2: option
3: option
accessKey: ""
ariaAtomic: null
ariaAutoComplete: null
ariaBusy: null
ariaChecked: null
ariaColCount: null
ariaColIndex: null
ariaColSpan: null
ariaCurrent: null
ariaDescription: null
ariaDisabled: null
ariaExpanded: null
ariaHasPopup: null
ariaHidden: null
ariaKeyShortcuts: null
ariaLabel: null
ariaLevel: null
ariaLive: null
ariaModal: null
ariaMultiLine: null
ariaMultiSelectable: null
ariaOrientation: null
ariaPlaceholder: null
ariaPosInSet: null
ariaPressed: null
ariaReadOnly: null
ariaRelevant: null
ariaRequired: null
ariaRoleDescription: null
ariaRowCount: null
ariaRowIndex: null
ariaRowSpan: null
ariaSelected: null
ariaSetSize: null
ariaSort: null
ariaValueMax: null
ariaValueMin: null
ariaValueNow: null
ariaValueText: null
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: name, 1: id, 2: class, name: name, id: id, class: class, length: 3}
autocapitalize: ""
autocomplete: ""
autofocus: false
baseURI: "https://test.team4work.net/profile.php"
childElementCount: 4
childNodes: NodeList(4) [option, option, option, option]
children: HTMLCollection(4) [option, option, option, option]
classList: DOMTokenList ["w2ui-input", value: "w2ui-input"]
className: "w2ui-input"
clientHeight: 21
clientLeft: 1
clientTop: 1
clientWidth: 111
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
dir: ""
disabled: false
draggable: false
elementTiming: ""
enterKeyHint: ""
firstChild: option
firstElementChild: option
form: null
hidden: false
id: "resp_company"
innerHTML: "<option value="0"> </option><option value="3">Bank of Toronto</option><option value="34">West Coast Bank</option><option value="37">American express</option>"
innerText: "Bank of Toronto↵West Coast Bank↵American express"
inputMode: ""
isConnected: true
isContentEditable: false
jQuery18309842176231417568: 514
labels: NodeList []
lang: ""
lastChild: option
lastElementChild: option
length: 4
localName: "select"
multiple: false
name: "resp_company"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: text
nodeName: "SELECT"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
nonce: ""
offsetHeight: 23
offsetLeft: 10
offsetParent: div.w2ui-page.page-0
offsetTop: 186
offsetWidth: 113
onabort: null
onanimationend: null
onanimationiteration: null
onanimationstart: null
onauxclick: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onbeforexrselect: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
onformdata: null
onfullscreenchange: null
onfullscreenerror: null
ongotpointercapture: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onlostpointercapture: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onpointercancel: null
onpointerdown: null
onpointerenter: null
onpointerleave: null
onpointermove: null
onpointerout: null
onpointerover: null
onpointerrawupdate: null
onpointerup: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectionchange: null
onselectstart: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
ontransitionend: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitanimationend: null
onwebkitanimationiteration: null
onwebkitanimationstart: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwebkittransitionend: null
onwheel: null
options: HTMLOptionsCollection(4) [option, option, option, option, selectedIndex: 3]
outerHTML: "<select name="resp_company" id="resp_company" class="w2ui-input"><option value="0"> </option><option value="3">Bank of Toronto</option><option value="34">West Coast Bank</option><option value="37">American express</option></select>"
outerText: "Bank of Toronto↵West Coast Bank↵American express"
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: div.w2ui-field
parentNode: div.w2ui-field
part: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: null
previousSibling: text
required: false
scrollHeight: 21
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 111
selectedIndex: 3
selectedOptions: HTMLCollection [option]
shadowRoot: null
size: 0
slot: ""
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
tabIndex: 0
tagName: "SELECT"
textContent: " Bank of TorontoWest Coast BankAmerican express"
title: ""
translate: true
type: "select-one"
validationMessage: ""
validity: ValidityState {valueMissing: false, typeMismatch: false, patternMismatch: false, tooLong: false, tooShort: false, …}
value: "37"
willValidate: true
__proto__: HTMLSelectElement
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#resp_company"
__proto__: Object(0)
```

---

@Igor Это значит что форма создается динамически вот так

```
<div class="w2ui-label">Company:</div>
 <div class="w2ui-field">
  <select name = "resp_company" id = "resp_company">
   <?php echo $compoption; ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

т.е. список формируется сервером и передается из php, а установка конкретного пункта меню из этого списка путем присвоения значения элементу по id="resp_company". Работающий пример больно здоровый для того, чтобы его тут выложить. Да и суть не в этом, при формировании формы с выбранным по умолчанию элементом select в случае разного его значения меняется поле value в том init что я выложил, это я четко вижу. Вот надо бы его и отследить. Иначе писать запрос к серверу, а это сложнее намного.

Comment: _val() возвращает значение первого элемента списка_ - это неверное утверждение

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="37" selected>American express</option>
```

---

> а установка конкретного пункта меню из этого списка путем присвоения
> значения элементу по id="resp_company"

Вы это делаете **после** того, как выполняется

```
companyfield = $('#resp_company').val();
```

Comment: Не совсем понял что имелось ввиду... Значение по умолчанию справедливо для конкретной формы, но может меняться при открытии иной формы. Надо это значение отследить.

Comment: @Alex Что значит "значение по умолчанию"? Создайте работающий пример.

Answer (score 0):

Вам уже писали в ответах

```
<select name="resp_company" id="resp_company" class="w2ui-input">
   <option value="0"></option>
   <option value="3">Bank of Toronto</option>
   <option value="34">West Coast Bank</option>
   <option value="37" selected>American express</option> 
</select>
```

selected показывает какое значение выбрано. По умолчанию поставил как вы и просили American express.
Теперь при обращении:

```
$('#resp_company').val();
```

Вы получите выбранный value.